# Getting error Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

In my database i have some columns which contain null value, and i have generated classes from the tables so there are int attributes for the columns containing integter datatype. Now the problem is if i query the database to get data i get this error "Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter" for the columns which have null value.
I also have read many solution which are saying to convert int to Integer, but i cant do that. There are many int columns which have same problem and if i have to generate entity classes from the tables through JPA again, JPA will again generate int attributes.
I am asking for a solution while querying that checks that if attribute value is null For Example person.salary IS NULL, the i store 0 in person.salary.
My query right now is like this

```
"Select per From Person per where id=1"
```

Its a Java persistence query language not a native sql query.
Any help will be highly appreciated. I cant change the queries to native sql query too. I am stuck on it from two days

Comment: do you use int, double or long and not Integer, Double, Long for some of your attributes?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer basically i am creating entity classes from tables using JPA, so JPA is creating the int attributes in entity classes for columns having datatype as int, i cant convert int to Integer as there are many attributes and the database schema can be changed for which i have to generate the entity classes again and JPA will again generate int.

Comment: If your field looks like `int salary` then it's normal that you get that error. After all, what do you think should be the value of `salary` in the entity if the database contains `NULL`? Hibernate doesn't know it and thus complains. So either change it to `Integer salary` or remove the `NULL` values.

Comment: @Thomas i cant do both, i have to something in query like if p.salary is null then change then set the p.salary as 0.

Comment: you will have to do one of the things. you can change all null values to 0 or whatever with just 1 query

Comment: Well in that case there's either a problem with ddl2hbm (probably some schema inconsistencies, could be a bug though) and thus you might want to not use it (in most cases it's not recommended for production use anyways) or change your query to use a "constructor expression".

Comment: @Thomas can you please guide me that how to use "constructor expression" or point me in right direction

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hibernate+constructor+expression

Comment: haha thankyou @Thomas